# Trying to open a .pdf file in an iframe

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat, crystal-reports-xi

I am really having a hard time opening up certain .pdf files within an iframe HTML element.  I can open some .pdf files in this iframe, but not all of them.  The ones that I cannot open were created by the Crystal Reports engine in Visual Studio 2010.

My source is simple and looks like the following:

```
<iframe src= "c:\jnk\EULA.pdf">
</iframe>
```

Is there any characteristic of a .pdf file that could prevent it from being displayed in an iframe?  I am using IE8, but get the same results in FF.  I also can perfectly display this .pdf file when it is not in an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

IFrame isn't correct solution. You can use other solutions :

1 . `<embed src="file:///C:\jnk\EULA.pdf" width="500" height="375">`

2 . Download [this](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library and use it.

I hope that I helped.

PS
Remember that when we use local file, we should write in prefix `file:///`

Sorry for my English

Comment: using embed gives me the same result as using iframe, but it gives me an error message "access denied" also

Comment: Are you using linux or windows ?

Comment: Windows, Visual Studio 2010, ASP.NET MVC3

Comment: Some other .pdf files function perfectly fine in the exact same iframe

Comment: I did not.  Since what I have already works with other .pdf files (just not the ones that I create via the Crystal engine), I want to go with it if I could.  I'm guessing there is just some attribute of the .pdf file that I need to change when I create it.  I will fall back on the library though if needed.  At this point the overhead with me getting it installed (I know nothing about installing it) and the learning curve of getting to know it may be more time than I have right now.

Answer (score -1):

Based on a comment of yours, it sounds like your issue is one of permissions, unrelated to PDFs.

If I were you, I'd make sure that I can access the PDFs in my browser outside of any HTML. If that fails, you know you have a problem.

Comment: This is what I initially thought.  I could access the .pdf file perfectly fine in a browser.  Just not in an iframe.

Comment: The only major differences I can find at this point between the pdfs that work and the ones that don't work is the "pdf producer" and the "pdf version"

Comment: What about their location? Are some network and others local?

Comment: I thought about this earlier and copied them all to the same location (my local drive)